# Is textAppearance and inbuilt theme attribute in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

I've been learning more concepts in Android and came across `textAppearance`.

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

I did some research on this and came to the conclusion that this syntax refers to attributes in the Theme whereas @ syntax refers to resources in the project / framework.

However, in my `theme.xml` file, I didn't define any item by the name of `textAppearanceLarge`. Therefore, I was wondering, is `textAppearance` and inbuilt item in the theme which Android provides?

Also, some background information on this topic would be really helpful.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `textAppearance` is inbuilt property of Android SDK.

`TextAppearance` allows you to define text-specific styling while leaving a View’s style available for other uses. Note, however, that if you define any text attributes directly on the View or in a style, those values would override the TextAppearance values.

`TextAppearance` supports a subset of styling attributes that TextView offers. For the full attribute list.

You can also read the following blog by Google developer to understand it in deep.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d

And also can refer to google documentation to understand the technical aspect of it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#textappearance

Comment: If this helped you please upvote as well. Thanks Dinkar

Comment: I'm a little confused on this : "TextAppearance allows you to define text-specific styling while leaving a View’s style available for other uses." What would the benefits of leaving a view's style available for other uses be? Thanks.

Comment: Textview is also have other part right like background and all so those will be taken care by View styling and text part of Textview can be styled by Textappearance

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use  `ctrl+ mouse_left_cllick` to explore .......basically, it will direct you to the exact code.